# photoshop question: clicking on subject shows on which layer it is

Tags: photoshop, psd

I can't find it anywhere;/ Do you guys know where I can change this option in photoshop? What I mean is:

we've got psd document with blue, red, yellow dots. Every dot is on separate layer:

```
Layer blabla
Group DOTTIE
  yellow dot
  red dot
  blue dot
Another Layer
```

When I clicked on the dot holding command/ctrl I want to be told which layer contains it. Default option is that clicking on yellow dot shows Group DOTTIE.. the same with red and blue..

I don't know if I making myself clear...

I would really apreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Superuser.com](http://superuser.com) is much more appropriate for questions related to software

That being said, with the Move tool selected, check the box in the top left corner (right below the top main menu) called "Auto Select" and then choose "Layer" instead of "Group" in the drop-down box right next to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to be of help ! :) Please be sure to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.